# Where to ask "office like" (e.g. LibreOffice Calc) questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am looking for "office" in the list of Stack Exchange sites, but I found no matches.

What is the site to ask such questions on, or are such questions not wanted?

Comment: Depends on what the question is, but there is a [libreoffice-calc tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice-calc) on StackOverflow

Comment: If it's not about programming, then even this meta question is off-topic. ;) Normally questions to recommend stack exchange site should be asked on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Sinatr: What "programming" means in office programs is an interesting question: Would "applying an adjusted formula to multiple rows" be "programming", or is it just usability? I was unsure; that's why I asked.

Comment: Note: The "recommended" question to look at has a significantly negative score (-4). Shouldn't recommended questions have a positive score (sorry for another meta-question ;-))

Answer (score 22):

[Superuser.com](https://superuser.com) is the natural home for end-user software questions.

Check their [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) guidance.

If the question is regarding scripting, macros, or formula usage... it *could* be on-topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice-calc). Although you should probably tread carefully.

Comment: "If the question is regarding scripting, macros, or formula usage" even if it's a question about those, I strongly discourage anyone from using SO to get answers. They are either substandard (read outdated by at least 4 generations) or flatly wrong.

Comment: @Braiam That's not an accurate (or fair)  representation of such question/answers on SO at all. Not only are questions being answered with up-to-date and high-quality solutions, but such categories are far from alone in having a subset of questions with low quality answers. In fact *all* tags suffer from low quality answers. I'm genuinely curious what prompted you to say such an outlandishly wrong thing.

Comment: @Braiam For example, just from a random sample of four of the top five [tag:vba] answerers on the site, [what](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55810023/2756409) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55817429/2756409) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55811242/2756409) [four](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55816969/2756409) answers (all from the last half-day, even) is substandard, outdated, or flatly wrong?

Comment: @TylerH that's and accurate representation of the 4 questions I had to search about access in the last 2 weeks. I was better off reading the documentation (which in some cases ranked higher, sadly not in all). Of the 2-3 answers per question, most were using obsolete versions of Access/VBA, at least one was wrong in a way that I knew that it was wrong. SO wasn't useful in those cases, made me waste time. That's why I recommend people to stay away from SO for Office apps. SO is better suited for software development.

Comment: @Braiam So because you had a bad experience with a random sample of old questions, you think SO is a bad place to ask new questions about different applications and their features, and that there are no good answers to be had? That's like scooping up a glass of ocean water on the beach, expecting to find pearls, and then complaining when there aren't any in your glass. And by the way, writing VBA *is* software development.

Comment: @TylerH no, SO is a bad experience in anything but software development. Sadly, those are the results that appear *first*, and I always feel lucky. This has happened with non-programming questions about everything, from nginx, windows, linux, mysql. Software developers, in average, aren't good system administrators nor power users, despite themselves believing so.

Comment: When I go to superuser.com, I get the same search menu for sites ("more stackexchange communities"), and when I enter "office" there, I still get no match. That's where I had been before sasking this question...

Comment: @U.Windl There is no site dedicated specifically to office suites. You either ask your question on superuser.com, or here, depending on what kind of question it is.

Comment: @yivi: I wonder: Couldn't there be something like "aliases": The user asks where to go with his question, maybe searching for "office". You don't have a dedicated site for such questions yet, but the search result could show something like "For <office> questions go to <recommended site>", or "There are many <office> tags in <name of site>; maybe post your question there".

Comment: @U.Windl That list would grow very fast and would have clashes. For example, you can ask questions about google-chrome in SU, SO, UL, AU, so, which site should appear on that placeholder?

Comment: @U.Windl That would be a separate Meta question, e.g. a [meta-tag:feature-request], and would more properly belong on Meta.SE, not here on Meta.SO. Superuser is the site for computer and program *use* questions.

Comment: @TylerH: Thanks! It's quite easy to get lost in the stack*|super* universe...

Comment: @U.Windl Tell me about it... I'm still finding new and interesting network sites!